# How to play sound samples continuously in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to play a continuous sine wave (for now) which changes its frequency (for now) according to the mouse pointer position (for now). So, I generate and play a wave of the length of one frame (1/2s in the code below). The resulting sound has small gaps in the sound, enough to be very notable. Increasing the duration of the individual sounds does not help, changing the buffer size does not help, using dtick instead of dt does not help.

Is there a way to achieve a continuous sound this way? Or any other way?

Thank you

Versions: Python 3.9.3, pygame 2.0.1

Minimal (still lengthy) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame import Color
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, KMOD_CTRL, QUIT, K_q

fade_out = np.linspace(1, 0, 100)
fade_in = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

bits = 16
sample_rate = 44100
max_sample = 2 ** (bits - 1) - 1


def gen_sound(duration, freq):
    n_samples = int(duration / 1000 * sample_rate)
    buf = np.zeros((n_samples, 2), dtype=np.int16)
    buf[:, 0] = (
        0.25
        * max_sample
        * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq[0] * np.arange(n_samples) / sample_rate)
    )
    buf[:, 1] = (
        0.25
        * max_sample
        * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq[1] * np.arange(n_samples) / sample_rate)
    )
    buf[-100:, 0] = (buf[-100:, 0] * fade_out).astype(int)
    buf[-100:, 1] = (buf[-100:, 1] * fade_out).astype(int)
    buf[:100, 0] = (buf[:100, 0] * fade_in).astype(int)
    buf[:100, 1] = (buf[:100, 1] * fade_in).astype(int)

    return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)


def main(argv: list = None):

    # initialize sound
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(sample_rate, -bits, 2, 512)

    # initialize pygame
    pygame.init()
    size = (1000, 800)
    surf = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    surf.fill(Color("black"))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # frames per second and duration of a frame in ms
    FPS = 2
    dt = 1000 / FPS
    dtick = 1000 / FPS
    # position of the mouse pointer, None means outside of the window
    mpos = None

    # event loop
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == QUIT:
                return
            # shutdown with C-q
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.mod & KMOD_CTRL and e.key == K_q:
                    return

        if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
            mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        else:
            mpos = None

        freq = mpos if mpos else (440, 440)
        sound = gen_sound(dt, freq)
        sound.play(loops=0, fade_ms=0)

        pygame.display.update()
        dtick = clock.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to use a cache for the generated wave so you don't re-build the wave if the frequency and duration haven't changed.  Also, if the sound plays in the background you want to update it at the time the sounds stops (unless there's a sound queue built into the player, which may well be.) rather than each loop of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly modify the `Sound` data while playing it, preventing the need to call `.play()` every frame.

```
def gen_sound(buf, freq):
    buf[:, 0] = (
            0.25
            * max_sample
            * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq[0] * np.arange(n_samples) / sample_rate)
    )
    buf[:, 1] = (
            0.25
            * max_sample
            * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq[1] * np.arange(n_samples) / sample_rate)
    )
```

and in main:

```
def main(argv: list = None):
    # ...

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    buf = np.zeros((n_samples, 2), dtype=np.int16)
    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(buf)
    buf = pygame.sndarray.samples(sound) # This is required because make_sound copies the array, but we want a reference
    gen_sound(buf, (440, 440))
    sound.play(loops=-1, fade_ms=0)

    # ...
    # event loop
    while True:
        # ...

        freq = mpos if mpos else (440, 440)
        gen_sound(buf, freq)

        pygame.display.update()
        dtick = clock.tick(FPS)
```

Note that this will run into the problem desribed and solved [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-to-create-a-sine-wave-generator-that-can-smoothly-transition-between-frequen), e.g. sin-wave transitions aren't smooth. But that is out of scope of this question and my knowledge.

Comment: That was the trick I was looking for. I suspected it to be possible, but didn't know how to write to the same buffer on the fly. And yes, the phase mismatch is another topic, thanks for the link. But at certain frequencies, I get a continuous sound which I couldn´t get before.

Comment: Even with a phase accumulator, how could this possibly work without clicks, if the sound buffer doesn't happen to be an exact multiple of cycles of the frequency? When the audio buffer loops, there is a discontinuity. The audio generation has to happen in sync with audio playback, not in sync with display refresh. For example in a double-buffering style: when audio playback is halfway through the buffer, gen_sound() starts writing the first half of the buffer. Then wait until audio output wraps, and gen_sound() to fill the second half. And repeat.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica That can still be done with clever code in gen_sound I think (i.e. keep track which part is currently being played and only override the other half). The generation doesn't need to be in sync with sound playing, it just needs to not conflict to much. But the exact code is still out-of-scope for my knowledge.

Comment: I was able to get completely smooth continuous sound output by filling the sound buffer in two halves and syncing to audio output position, but it's a huge kludge. One problem is that the Sound object returned from pygame.sndarray.make_sound() cannot be asked about the current playback position like pygame.mixer.music can with the get_pos() method. I had to load a dummy audio file with pygame.mixer.music and play it simultaneously with the buffer sound, to get an audio output position. But the position isn't completely accurate, I have to subtract around 30 milliseconds from music.get_pos().

Comment: IMO, to properly support continuous application-generated audio streams without shaky kludges, there should be explicit support for buffer switching and syncing. This is maybe a little outside Pygame's intended application domain. ;) The SDL backend definitely supports that, but I don't currently know enough about Python and Pygame to add the needed facilities. Maybe it's possible to at least get the current playback position from pygame.sndarray.make_sound()'s Sound object.